# php searching question

Tags: php, search

I have a lot of php code and I'm going through it right now (500+ files). I was hoping to find a program that would let me easily search through the files to see which files contain a specific variable I am editing. Kind of like a super edit -> find from notepad++. Anyone have any suggestions?

Best,
Pavan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One word. [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/).

Comment: I was introduced to ack ~6 months ago - not sure how I ever lived without it.  (Actually I do know: with a cheap ack-wannabe Perl script I've been toting around for 10 years)  Since then I haven't met a serious developer who was shown ack and didn't embrace it.

Comment: @beamrider9 Did you find it better than the find in files feature of notepad++?

Comment: @Pavan I don't know that app, sorry.  My text editor of choice has a "find in files" also, but ack is a command line tool, which I find generally more useful in situations like this.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try [Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=agentransack&page=home)

Comment: Checking it out now. Thanks NAVEED!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a PHP ide such as [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org/) or your alternative is if you want to stick with notepad++ you can the `Find in files` which is located in the last tab when you hit `CTRL+F`

using [NetBeans IDE](http://www.netbeans.org/) you can lay your project out into a really decent code profiler and be able to see what your code is doing from a visual prospective.

Comment: Thanks dude. I just checked out the find in files thing and it rocks. Wish it did it right on the server, but I shouldn't be editing on the server anyway.